# Hololense 2 development on Unity Buildtime error?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

for reference I am following this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrlearning-base-ch1

I am unable to build a scene in the assets folder.

[image: Screen Shot of Unity Console Error Message]

I have ran through the dependencies multiple times and believe I have all the current requirements accounted for. If anyone has any idea on where the culprit for the error might be that would be awesome.

Comment: Please post a snipped of your code and try adding the stack trace as a text too. People will be more responsive if you do so.

Comment: @Cabrra the exceptions have nothing to do with the code, though ;)

Answer (score 3):

It is exactly as the error say:

Apparently you are trying to build to a location inside the `Assets` folder but

> Building to the `Assets` folder is not allowed

→ simply use another folder outside of the `Assets` as build target usually e.g. `<project path>\Build` or in the [linked tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrlearning-base-ch1#build-your-application-to-your-device) they use the folder `<project path>\App` btw ;)

---

Maybe you confused it with [Configure the Mixed Reality Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/mixed-reality/mrlearning-base-ch1#configure-the-mixed-reality-toolkit)→Step 2: creating a new Scene `BaseScene.unity` file which has to be stored inside the `Assets`.